# tbl_merge add p value ? with gt summar package R

Tags: r, p-value, gtsummary

I am a beginner in r and trying to create some tables using this great gtsummary package. My question is that is it possible to add p value on this ?

```
merge <- tbl_merge(
    tbls = list(gene_colt, colt),
    tab_spanner = c("**gene COLT**", "**COLT**")
  )%>% add_p()
```

[image: output]

Comment: You want a p-value comparing gene COLT to COLT? tbl_merge merges two tables but won't do an actual comparison across tables. What you will need to do is row bind the gene COLT and COLT data sets and then stratify by gene COLT and COLT, make one table and add_p()

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. The package is well-documented and you can find more information under [this link](https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/reference/add_p.tbl_summary.html). I would recommend to define the statistical test in the function, e.g., `%>% add_p(test = "chisq.test")` for a Chi-squared test. For a reference of what else is possible I would refer you to [the documentation](https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/reference/tests.html) once again for lack of information in your question, i.e., it is unclear which test you would like to apply.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I understand that I can easily add p values ​​to arrays. But in my case I show you two arrays that are merged. So how to compare its values ​​and add p values ? @freyberg

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you merge your data before creating two separate tables, and add a new variable, e.g. `table_id`, to distinguish `COLT` data from `gene COLT` data.

Then you can run the following:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gtsummary)

merged_data <-   # this will depend on how your data were structured...
    bind_rows(
        data1 %>% mutate(table_id = "gene COLT"),
        data2 %>% mutate(table_id = "COLT")
    )

merged_data %>%
tbl_summary(
    data = .,
    by = table_id
    ) +
    add_p(test = "chisq.test")
```